# Linux use output command 1 in command 2

Tags: linux

I'm using `cat /sys/class/net/eth0/address` to find the mac address of my raspberry

I need to use the output of `cat /sys/class/net/eth0/address` (the mac adress), in a new command.

How can I do that?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using bash or similar shell you can simply use

```
new_command $(cat /sys/class/net/eth0/address)
```

Comment: That will provide the output as arguments to... If you need it as input you need to use (in bash) *process substitution* instead of *command substitution*, e.g. `new_command < <(cat /sys/class/net/eth0/address)` -- which should actually be a simple redirection `new_command < /sys/class/net/eth0/address` as `sysfs` can be read as files.

Answer (score 1):

output redirection using `pipes` like `cmd1 | cmd2` you need to do that in a way like `cmd1` output should be input to `cmd2` as

```
xyz@my_system:~/april-15$ cat cmd1 | cmd2
                               |      |
                            o/p of   new command
                            1st cmd
```

Answer (score 1):

one way to do it is to use the pipe where the output of your first cmd will become the argument of your second cmd

```
cat /sys/class/net/eth0/address | YournewCmd
```